# Magento script duration

Tags: magento-1.8, product, shell

i have written a magento script to get skus of products from a csv file and update them in stock and assign a category. It works fine just it takes a very long time, more then 2 hours for just 14 000 skus!
I want to know is this normal behaviour.
My question is if there something i can to optimize the code.

Here is a snippet of code.

```
 $product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->loadByAttribute('sku', $sku);
    if ($product) 
            {
            $product->load($product->getId());
                         if($qty > 0) {           
                     $product->setStockData(array(
                   'use_config_manage_stock' => 0,
                   'manage_stock'=>1,
                   'min_sale_qty'=>0,
                   'use_config_min_sale_qty'=>0,
                   'max_sale_qty'=>0,
                   'is_in_stock' => 1, 
                   'qty' => $qty
                                )
                         );     
              $product->setCategoryIds($categories);
              $product->getResource()->save($product);
```

Comment: Can you please provide full function?

Comment: Hi, there is a similar question here: http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/116110/avoiding-memory-exhaustion-when-updating-product-stock/116115#116115
1. Use a resource iterator, 2. avoid loading/saving the entire product model,

Comment: Is there another function/way to use like  `setStockData` to update the same parameters more efficiently ?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, this is normal behavior. Especially when you have such a quantity of processed products.

But you can go to the System/Index Management and set to Manual Update indexes for the duration of your script. This might speed up the process.