# Rewriting resource model

Tags: magento-1.8, module, overrides, resource-model

I am trying to follow the answer of this question [Avoiding memory exhaustion when updating product stock?](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/116110/avoiding-memory-exhaustion-when-updating-product-stock) to rewrite a resource model. I created a custom module and is activated in the back-office. Here is my `config.xml`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

 <config>
            <modules>
               <Mymodule_Vendor>
                    <version>0.1.0</version>
                </Mymodule_Vendor_Vendor>
             </modules>

       <models>
            <vendor>
               <class>Mymodule_Vendor_Model</class>
              <resourceModel>vendor_cataloginventory_resource</resourceModel>
      </vendor>

 <cataloginventory_resource>
      <rewrite>
             <stock_item>Mymodule_Vendor_Model_CatalogInventory_Resource_Stock_Item</stock_item>
      </rewrite>
 </cataloginventory_resource>
       </models>

 </config>
```

When i do this :

```
$stockItem = Mage::getModel('cataloginventory/stock_item')->loadByProduct($product)->setData('is_in_stock', $quantity > 0 ? 1 : 0)->setQty($quantity);
$stockItem->getResource()->saveAttribute($stockItem,array('is_in_stock','qty'));
```

Directories structure :
`app/code/local/Mymodule/Vendor/:
     -Model/CatalogInventory/Resource/Stock : item.php
     -etc : config.xml`

I get this error :
`Fatal error: Call to undefined method Mage_CatalogInventory_Model_Resource_Stock_Item::saveAttribute()`

I solved the error but i got another one:

> Fatal error: Call to a member function loadByProduct() on a non-object

when i try this :

```
     $quantity = 8;
     $product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->loadByAttribute('sku',$sku);
     $productId = $product->getId();
     $product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($productId);
     $stockItem = Mage::getModel('cataloginventory/stock_item')->loadByProduct($product)->setData('is_in_stock', $quantity > 0 ? 1 : 0)->setQty($quantity);
 $stockItem->getResource()->saveAttribute($stockItem,array('is_in_stock','qty');
```

I didn't one to create another question so i edited this one.

Answer (score 1):

The directory structure you have above is incorrect for the models.

> app/code/local/Vendor/CatalogInventory/Model/Resource/Stock/Item.php

**`CatalogInventory`** and **`Model`** were inverted in yours.

Magento can't find this in local so is trying to load **`Mage/CatalogInventory/...`** rather than **`Vendor/CatalogInventory`**.

Adding the Firegento Debugger plugin certainly helps to identify this sort of issue when creating new modules.

Comment: Your answer solved the loading of the method. I edited the question with another issue.

Comment: Might be better to add this as a second question.

try removing 
$productId = $product->getId();
$product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($productId);

as you already have the $product from the previous line

Answer (score 0):

As its a rewrite and you're defining new resource models you should simply remove the entire `<resourceModel>` node.

Comment: I removed the node but i still have the error.

Comment: This wouldn't be related to the problem I wouldn't imagine, although it's true